# When browser is resided part of the header background is missing

Tags: html, css

[image: Screen capture of the issue]

The header in the pic is styled in 3 parts the top part contains a div with the width 100% and background color and inside the dive there is a div styled as a container which holds all elements at the top. This container has a width of 1000px and min-width of 960px and margin: 0 auto;

but when u re-size the browser and scroll with the scroll-er at the bottom the header appears as follows.

What am I doing wrong here for it to render this way?

CSS

```
#header {
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 15px;
```

}

```
#header .nav-content-holder {
    width: 1000px;
    min-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header .header-menu-top {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #d8d4cf;
    color: @Color-Txt-black;
}

#header .header-menu-middle {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: @Color-FM-brown;
    color: @Color-Txt-white;
}

#header .header-menu-bottom {
    border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    height: 28px;
    background-color: @Color-FM-brown;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: @Color-Txt-white;
}
```

HTML

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: pass the  height width in percentage

Comment: Without any code it is impossible to know what is going on with this image.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code before. I updated the question with the code.

Comment: @Vickey passing as % do not help in this situation. I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code it is impossible to know what is going on but you need to try  `min-width: 1040px;` on body.